# LNK1104 Microsoft Visual Studio Error

Tags: c++

My problem is LNK1104 :

> cannot open file libcpmt.lib .

I have to use Platform Toolset v120_xp to have compatibility with windows xp, also i have to use /MT option in Project properties>C/C++>Code Generation>Runtime Library. How can I fix it ? 
@up

Comment: Do you have libcpmt.lib? Are you linking it in your program?

Comment: Make sure that you are using 32 bit libraries and your project is 32 bit and that all of the dependencies for your application were built with the same toolset.

Comment: @drescherjm Project is build in 32 bit libraries, and working on 64 bit os. I would like to say that on normal Platform Toolset program work...

Comment: @Litty How can see it ? It worked before i change Platform Toolset

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries? If so did you recompile them with the v120_xp toolset?

Comment: @drescherjm I'm using only with C++11 Libraries. This is console program, so i don't have to use third party libraries.

Comment: Did you try a clean build?

Comment: @drescherjm What do you mean ? I was builded on default Platform Toolset, and it was worked. It were  worked with this Toolset , but not on /MT mode. It were worked on /MD mode

Comment: I mean to rebuild all for your entire solution after making the change.

Comment: @drescherjm This same error...

Comment: Maybe this line from Output window will help you and me to resolve problem. :LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'

Comment: @drescherjm On debug mode it work ! I'm sure that the problem is in /MT option ....